# C# Win form. Getting a list of books displayed in a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the book author and the book title displayed in my rich text box. Here is a sample of my code:

```
        // Opretter info på bog
        book.Author = "Hej Preben";
        book.Title = "Hvem sagde hej?";

        // tilføjer bogen til metoden
        library.AddBook(book);
        richTextBoxBooks.Text = library.GetAllBooks().ToString();
```

The GetallBooks is returning title and author (and a id), but when i look at my windows form, my textbox is displaying this: [image: Rich text box]

My list is working, I just want to know how I can get the correct info displayed, insted of this.

Im feeling stuck, so have not tried many things

Comment: Your `library.GetAllBooks()` is not returning a `string` representing all books. It is a returning an object that contains information about all books. You need to further parse that object into `string`s and then set the `.Text`. // Without knowing what `Book` and `Library` class look like, it's tough to say much more.

Comment: You can override ToString() in your Book class, to return whatever property values you want (e.g., `return $"Author: {Author}, Title: {Title}";`), then just join the results, as in `richTextBoxBooks.Text = string.Join("\n", GetAllBooks());` -- You can also set that list as the DataSource of a DataGridView, for a more *sensible* presentation. Or generates SubItems of a ListView and so on...

Comment: You need a method to generate a List<string> of book titles.  Then you decide whether to list in Title order, or by Author and then Title.  Or you can use a DataGridView and list different book properties (Title, Author, Date) by using a binding list to bind the Books collection to the DataGridView.

Comment: Use a foreach loop on your list and create a string that will show proper in your textbox.  You will need to think about how to create new line's and possibly what ever else for appearance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

**Book and Library classes**

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal class Book
    {
        public string Author { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public Book(string author, string title)
        {
            Author = author;
            Title = title;
        }
    }

    internal class Library
    {
        private List<Book> _books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
        public void AddBook(Book book)
        {
            _books.Add(book);
        }
        public List<Book> GetAllBooks()
        {
            return _books;
        }
    }
}
```

**Button click event**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var library = new Library();
    library.AddBook(new Book("Author One", "Title One"));
    library.AddBook(new Book("Author Two", "Title Two"));
    library.AddBook(new Book("Author Three", "Title Three"));

    foreach (Book book in library.GetAllBooks())
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = $"{richTextBox1.Text}{book.Author} - {book.Title}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop on your list:

```
    string books = "";
    foreach(var item in someList)//replace someList with name of your list
      { //as long as [0] is not id you will have [0], [1], [2] to choose from

        books += item[0].ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + item[1].ToString();
   
      }

richTextBoxBooks.Text = books;
```

I woud also make yor textbox read only, and multiline.
someList could be replaced by library.GetAllBooks() as long as it returns a list.